# iPhone - Load a new UIView on pressing button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

say I have a UITableView and upon selecting a new table row (thus firing the delegate method), I want to load a new UIView (which I have created in storyboard) and pass to it a data item.

Obviously the new UIView is added as a UIViewController in storyboard and has its own controller class..

How would I go about doing that?

Thank you!

Comment: i have posted you an answer - but note this: try to google your questions first, there are hundreds of tableview tutorials out there that can help you, and they pop up on google if you search for them =)

Comment: You're right, but sometimes formulating the right question to put into google is difficult.. But I will keep your suggestion in mind. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: no problem :)
i googled for `2 level uitableview tutorial`, just ask google exactly what you want, its surprisingly understanding :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something along the lines of this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: that link is now dead. Can you edit your answer so it still makes sense without the link?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using storyboards and not XIB files, use this code...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    DetailViewController *dvController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
}
```

Also you need to set the "Identifier" field in Interface  Builder to the name used in `self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`

Cheers!